# How can I get the difference between 2 branches based on certain file extension?

Tags: git

Could not find a difference filtering certain file types? I just want to compare .js files for example between branch a and b?

Comment: What output do you expect here?  Are you asking for a combined diff of several JS files?

Comment: I want to see differences but i am only interested in the *.js files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter git diff based on file extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554776/how-to-filter-git-diff-based-on-file-extensions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+diff+file+extension

Comment: Does the answer no longer apply?

Answer (score 4):

Does this simply work?

```
git diff branch-a branch-b -- '*.js'
```

If you want to have a more complete view:

```
git diff branch-a branch-b -- $(cat <(git ls-tree --name-only -r branch-a) <(git ls-tree --name-only -r branch-b) | sort | uniq | grep '\.js$')
```

---

What does this super-long command do?

This part should be obvious, the `--` at the end of this part means all subsequent arguments are file paths, not options

```
git diff branch-a branch-b --
```

Let's take a look at this giant command:

```
$(cat <(git ls-tree --name-only -r branch-a) <(git ls-tree --name-only -r branch-b) | sort | uniq | grep '\.js$')
```

The first thing is this:

```
cat <(git ls-tree --name-only -r branch-a) <(git ls-tree --name-only -r branch-b)
```

This uses `git ls-tree` to list all files in commits, and use `cat` to collect the output of files in the two branches. `<()` is a shell substitution, which is replaced by the name of a pipe. The other side of the pipe is apparently the output of `git ls-tree`.

```
| sort | uniq | grep '\.js$'
```

Sort and filter the combined files - in practice there are likely may duplicates, so `uniq` takes duplicated stuff out. `grep '\.js$'` at the end filters to show only files whose path ends in `.js`.

The result of the long command in `$()` is the combined `.js` files in both branches, which is then passed to `git diff` to filter diff files. This is exactly what you want, if I correctly understand.

---

What about packing this into a convenient shell script for later use?

```sh
#!/bin/sh
SOURCE=${1:-master}
TARGET=${2:-HEAD}
FILTER=${3:-.*}
exec git diff $SOURCE $TARGET -- $(cat <(git ls-tree --name-only -r $SOURCE) <(git ls-tree --name-only -r $TARGET) | sort | uniq | grep "$FILTER")
```

Usage:

```
./diff-all.sh branch-a branch-b '\.js$'
```

Comment: Actually, you can just quote the `*.js` part to get Git to do the same thing: `git diff branch-a branch-b -- '*.js'`. The arguments after `--` are pathspec arguments, which can be more than just file names. You just need to be sure the shell doesn't eat the `*` by expanding `*.js` to all the top level `*.js` files, before Git gets hold of it.

Comment: @torek I should have remembered that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @iBug Good one, how can I do this for multiple file types filter, something like this `git diff branch-a branch-b -- $(cat <(git ls-tree --name-only -r branch-a) <(git ls-tree --name-only -r branch-b) | sort | uniq | grep '(\.js|\.vue|\.php)$')` is possible ?