# How to filter git diff based on file type?

Tags: git

Is there an option to restrict `git diff` to show only a given set of file types?

By types I mean only regular files, symlinks, submodules, etc, as listed non exhaustively in the description of [`--diff-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203).

I am particularly interested in getting a diff containing only regular files.

Note that this question is not the same as [How to filter git diff based on file extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554776/how-to-filter-git-diff-based-on-file-extensions)

**EXAMPLE**: Suppose I have this output

```
git diff --raw HEAD^^ HEAD
:100644 100644 8e994d8 c79147d M        lib/esq.txt
:000000 120000 0000000 daee357 A        lib/file
```

where `lib/file` is a symlink.

Is there some option to pass to `git diff` to exclude the symlink from the output, or do I have to filter the output outside of Git by testing the modes?

Thanks

Comment: The `--diff-filter` argument itself only filters on the state (A, M, etc); if you want to filter on the `mode` field, use `git diff --raw` to get the raw output, and then use awk or grep or similar to collect interesting lines and/or discard uninteresting ones. For instance, `awk '$2 != "120000" { print }'` would filter out the `lib/file` line above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to create a list of the files (with find, for example), then you could use xargs.... hopefully it should work:

```
find ./ whateverfilter | xargs git diff
```

That should work.

Comment: Your answer only works if the files are present on the working tree.I have updated my question with an example, for which your answer will not work. Please, check it out.