# Git name only and patterns

Tags: git, formatting

I have a notebook.ipynb with one cell that has the following code `def test(     ): return "yes"`
and another script.py that has one line of code: `test="test"`

So I run the following command:

```
black --$(git diff --name-only -- *.ipynb -- *.py)
```

My terminal shows one change on the `notebook.ipynb` and no change on the `script.py`

How should I use the command `git diff --name-only` ?

Comment: Note that besides fixing up your `git diff`, you probably want a space after the `--` in `black --$(...)` (i.e., `black -- $(...)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following "[How to filter git diff based on file extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8554776/6309)", I would first test the diff command alone:

```
git diff --name-only -- '*.ipynb' '*.py'
                    ^^^
                only one --
```

Or:

```
git diff --name-only -- *.{ipynb,py}
```

Once that is working, you can include the `diff` command in your more general command.

Comment: @abdellah Great! Well done. Which of the two options worked?

Comment: I used the second one